# Getting unique values for last two columns

Tags: sas, dataset, unique

Would like to get first values for columns new.Price and new.Month based on columns price and month columns if NUM and fruits are unique. If num is unique and fruits are unique then if price repeats for 3 times as 1, for the first instance it should be populated unique value 1 and rest of them should be null.
Please find the attached picture and would like to get the data based on it

[image]

Comment: The photograph of your data is very pretty, but also very hard to code with.

Comment: Why do the values or `New.Action` (note variables names cannot contain periods) match the values of `Price`? Is that what you want?  If not then why is the third non-missing value a `1` and not a `3`?  Same for `New.Relation`, are the values supposed to match the value of `Month`?

Comment: @Tom Thanks for your reply we are trying this on some other data this is a simulated data which I have projected. Please let me know the logic in SAS, how to get the last 2 columns

Comment: I don't care if the data is real or not, I can't paste a photograph into a program.

Comment: When you post an image and ask for code that means we have to type out the numbers to work with it and then test the code and post an answer. It's much easier and faster if you post your data as text to start with.

Comment: @Reeza Sure will do it from next time

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your description is trying to say but your photograph makes it look like you just want to use `FIRST.` processing.  Since the data is grouped, but not fully sorted you can use the NOTSORTED keyword on the BY statement.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by num fruits price month notsorted;
  if first.price then new_action =price;
  if first.month then new_relation = month;
run;
```